# Vector addition with vector indexing

Tags: r

This may well have an answer elsewhere but I'm having trouble formulating the words of the question to find what I need.

I have two dataframes, A and B, with A having many more rows than B. I want to look up a value from B based on a column of A, and add it to another column of A. Something like:

```
A$ColumnToAdd + B[ColumnToMatch == A$ColumnToMatch,]$ColumnToAdd
```

But I get, with a load of NAs:

```
Warning in `==.default`: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I could do it with a messy for-loop but I'm looking for something faster & elegant.

Thanks

Comment: If `A` has many more rows than `B`, how is `B$ColumnToMatch == A$ColumnToMatch` supposed to work? In other words, please add a reproducible example with an expected outcome to clarify things.

Comment: Hi, This sounds like what we call a `merge` or `join` - type question. Have a look at for instance the help examples for `dplyr::inner_join`. These should show you how to create a single DF with both columns and matching rows from both data.frames - then you can do a simple `sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for a [merge](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html) or a [join](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html), as suggested in the comments.

Here's a simple example for both using dummy data that should fit what you described.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Some dummy data
ColumnToAdd <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
ColumnToMatch  <- c('a','b','b','b','c','a','c','d')
A <- data.frame(ColumnToAdd, ColumnToMatch)
ColumnToAdd <- c(1,2,3,4)
ColumnToMatch <- c('a','b','c','d')
B <- data.frame(ColumnToAdd, ColumnToMatch)

# Example using merge
A %>% 
  merge(B, by = c("ColumnToMatch")) %>%  
  mutate(sum = ColumnToAdd.x + ColumnToAdd.y)                    

# Example using join
A %>% 
  inner_join(B, by = c("ColumnToMatch")) %>% 
  mutate(sum = ColumnToAdd.x + ColumnToAdd.y)
```

[The advantages of the dplyr versions over merge are](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/manipulatr/OuAPC4VyfIc):

- rows are kept in existing order
- much faster
- tells you what keys you're merging by (if you don't supply)
- also work with database tables.